# How do I concatenate two strings with jq when one of them might be null?

Tags: json, null, jq

I'm trying to parse AWS instance metadata to take two values and combine them into one string (a name and an id).  The name is sometimes empty, and jq doesn't want to append to null.  How do I tell jq to just assume the null value is an empty string?  I've seen mentions of a "destructuring" operator, or a map function to do this, but I can't seem to get any of that syntax to work.

It may further complicate things, but the name is stored as the value in a key-value tag.  I have to do a select like this to get the name: `.Tags[]|select(.Key == "Name").Value`.

Here's some sample data:

```
{
  "InstanceId": "i-abc",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "Grafana"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "InstanceId": "i-def"
}
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```
cat sample.json |jq -r '.|{together: (.InstanceId + " " + (.Tags[]|select(.Key == "Name").Value) // empty)}'
{
  "together": "i-abc Grafana"
}
jq: error (at <stdin>:12): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Comment: I just tried rearranging my sample json so I don't have to query the tag.  I'm able to get the 'null' name to change to an empty string when I try that.  So what's the syntax to make that work when the Name isn't there in a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate things:

- Get rid of the no-op `.|`
- Use the error-suppression operator (`?`) when accessing the optional property.
- The empty string is `""`, not `empty`. `empty` is a generator which generates nothing (with somewhat confusing effects).
- Add parentheses to group expressions/define operator precedence.

```
{ together: (.InstanceId + " " + ((.Tags[]|select(.Key == "Name").Value)? // "")) }
```

Output:

```json
{
  "together": "i-abc Grafana"
}
{
  "together": "i-def "
}
```

If you don't want to have the trailing blank, go with 0stone0's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses to exclude `.InstanceId` but include `" " + …` when failing:

```bash
{together: (.InstanceId + ((.Tags[] | " " + select(.Key == "Name").Value)? // ""))}
```

```json
{
  "together": "i-abc Grafana"
}
{
  "together": "i-def"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/B9ezLjjEbmO)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to generate an array using `select()`, end then let `join(" ")` deal with the rest:

```
{ together: [ .InstanceId, (.Tags[]? | select(.Key=="Name").Value)  ] | join(" ") }
```

```json
{
  "together": "i-abc Grafana"
}
{
  "together": "i-def"
}
```

---

##### [JqPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/B9ezLjjEbmO)

Answer (score 0):

Before I got an answer, I asked a friend for help.  He responded with another method:

```
cat sample.json|jq -r '((.Tags[]|select(.Key == "Name").Value)? // "") as $name|{together: (.InstanceId + " " + $name)}'
```